# Possible to use javascript to create a static-border/having webpages slide between one another

Tags: javascript, jquery, static, border, sliding

edit: I don't want to just take content from different pages and load it into the current page. What I really want to do is load different html files that will be interactive within the television. I have found that it is difficult to do this because you can't load html files into DIV's and you can't click on links through a transparent png file.

Hello,

I am building a website for a tv show that my friends and I make called Every Single Day.

here you can see the mock up of what I have so far:
http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/cs195/final/S/S.html

as of right now, the image I am using is just one big image that I sliced up with Photoshop.

What my goal is, is to use some sort of script to make it so the outside television will stay in place statically and the web-content within the television will transition without reloading the outer-most television.

I wanted to combine this technique with something similar to the fss slider script to allow each page on the site to slide, making it look like it is a continuation of the room. -Perhaps this isn't even the best way to achieve my desired result.

I have all of my images drawn and sliced, all I need now is some direction in what exactly to search for to find the pieces I am looking for.

Thank you very much, I am pleased to have joined this community,

cooper reid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 5: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/10/ (Shows addition content.)

---

Edit 4: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/7/

This demo includes panning to specific frames.

```
var h = $('.clickable div').height(); //height of a single content DIV
var divCount = 0;
$('.clickable div').each(function() { divCount++; }); //count number of content DIVs

$('.pan').click(function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action (of <a>)
    if ($('.content div').is(':animated')) return false; //disable click while animating
    var x = $(this).attr('href'); x = $(x).index(); //get index of destination element
    $('.content div').animate({top: -x*h +'px'}, 2000); //animate to destination
});

$('#tv-right').click(function() {

    if ($('.content div').is(':animated')) return false; //disable click while animating
    $('.content div').animate({top: '-='+h+'px'}, 2000); //animation

    //if last div then go back to the start
    if ($('.content div:last').css('top') == (-h * (divCount - 1)) +"px") {
        $('.content div').stop().animate({ top: '0px' }, 1000);
    }
});
```

---

Edit 3: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/5/

Ok, check this demo out. Clicking on the right side of the TV (where you may put some buttons) will scroll the content in the screen. When you reach the last content section, the next click will return to the first content section. I layered the content so the background divs scroll behind the TV image and the content scrolls above (so you can click on it. There are a few other tricks thrown in but look it over and you should get the idea.

---

Edit 2: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/3/ (Click the TV to see the transition. This has content divs instead of just a background image).

Edit: Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/pqAJK/

---

I would first cut out the screen part of the TV and save it has a .png with transparency so you can see what is behind the screen portion of the TV.

Then you can add a background image and animate that with jQuery to slide into view the portion you would like to display.

I *personally wouldn't use any slices, kind of an old school technique for when most people didn't have high speed connections.

Comment: what is the most recent technique for cutting up an image?
I like hand drawing my site-so i always thought slicing it up was a good method

Comment: These days I only cut images when needed, as in for layout purposes. Check out the demo link I posted. The TV is just one image set in a DIV. I cut out the screen in Photoshop and saved it as a .png with transparency so you can see through the screen area. Then I used a long background (set with CSS) and used a little jQuery to animate the background position.

Comment: @cooper Check out the 2nd demo link I posted. Shows you how this can be achieved not only with a background image but also content divs.

Comment: thats really sweet. Could i jsut use that in combination with waitingforatrain's idea to use ajax .get to load the webpage without refreshing?

Comment: @cooper What kind of content will you be loading? I don't think ajax is necessary here unless you have a ton of content or very large file sizes.

Comment: just html files with sliced up images

Comment: but i also want to add buttons to the outside tv border

Comment: @cooper Also, do you want the user to be able to click on areas inside the TV image or do you just want to display content?

Comment: @wdm yea i want the user to be able to click inside the tv as well

Comment: @cooper Ok I'm playing around with a solution now. It's a little tricky (because it's not wanting to let me click through to the content behind the TV transparency) but I have an idea to make it work. Give me a bit and I'll post what I come up with.

Comment: @wdm thanks a lot things are always more complicated then they seem but I am learning a lot in the process, thank again

Comment: @cooper Ok, think I have this working pretty good. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: @wdm wow thanks a lot thats pretty much exactly what i was looking for.
im going to start trying to implement it, I will let you know how it goes

Comment: While I understand the general idea of what you have sent me, I still don't know how I would get the page to load within the TV. Do I have to use the actual picture that I originally used for the page, or can I use the html file I have all cut and sliced? would it make sense to call a get method similar to what waitinforatrain posted earlier?

Comment: @cooper All of the content that you see transitioning is already within the page (see it in the HTML?), the DIVs with classes "a" through "e" are the backgrounds which move behind the TV and the 2nd group of DIVs are the corresponding "clickable" content that scroll above portions of the TV (so users can click on links and whatnot). I am using CSS (such as overflow:hidden) so you cannot see them all at once. This method should give you the cleanest effect. Start by creating one TV image (no slices) with the center cut out and save-for-web as .png (with transparency).

Comment: ... Then scale the widths/heights in the CSS of my example to correspond with the size of your TV. Also if you're not sure how things work exactly I would remove one piece at time from the CSS to see how they impact the page (like remove "overflow:hidden" and see what happens).

Comment: @wdm I now fully understand everything within the code you have given me but I am beginning to think this won't work. When I click a link within the content of the tv, I was hoping this would load the content back into the tv without a refresh. I also need to be able to have html files within the tv and you can't put an html file in a div, only image files. Please correct me if I am wrong and thank you so much for giving me some direction, I am learning a lot!

Comment: I think you will get a better idea of what I am trying to do if you click the television(that says day) link on the site. As you can see the page that loads is of the same room as the homepage. this being said, I was hoping that when you click the link of the television that says day, a new page would slide in from the right and the old page would slide out to the left. All of this would be done with no refresh on the outermost television

Comment: You can slide to specific DIVs via links (like a bookmark in theory). I have to run out for a few hours but if you cannot figure what I mean I'll put together an example later today.

Comment: yea i still don't fully understand

i have a bunch of computer architecture hw and will be back in a couple hours to continue this
thanks wdm talk to you later

Comment: @cooper See my latest edit/demo. Also I just noticed your edit in your original question. You can load html (on demand) from a file into a div via Ajax, or you can load all the html in a page and either scroll to it (as in my example) or there are other methods of manipulation to show/hide content. You can also use a combination of these (which you may end up doing). jQuery offers a wealth of resources for manipulating the DOM. This really begins with knowing the limits of the DOM, jQuery and CSS and using these together to achieved the desired effect.

Comment: As you can see though from my examples things get more and more complex as you add functionality. I hope this gives you some helpful direction in order to achieve your goals.

Comment: @wdm ok, so I have the background image cut into divs and I have my page layed-out within the divs. To allow the scroll I just changed it in the content class. I thought everything was right on, but now I don't seem to have the ability to click on any of the content


heres a link to the site: 
http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/cs195/final/S/biography/biography.html

any idea why?

Comment: @cooper There are some problems with your CSS. Rather than rewrite what you have, lets go back to what I created. Before that let me say that you have to ditch the slices and tables. For now forget such things ever existed, trust me on this. Ok, now lets look at my code (see Edit 5). I have two sections wrapped in DIVs. One has class="content bg" (these are the bg (background) divs). The other has class="content clickable" which is the content you want the user to be able to "click". The background will go behind the TV, the clickable will flow in front (for the most part).

Comment: First let's take advantage of the repeating background pattern. In my new code I cut out a section that can be repeated seamlessly. I assigned this image (in the CSS) to the .bg (background) DIVs. You can use different images in each if you'd like but it seems like you want to keep the background consistant. OK now we can leave those alone and move onto the "clickable" section. In each DIV here you can place content. I cut out the background areas from your picture-frame images and saved them as .png with transparency. You can layer your webpage similar to how you would layer in Photoshop.

Comment: I set these as backgrounds within A tags (links). This way you can use a css hover effect instead of javascript. I'm using a "sprite" technique which is one large image that changes position to show the hover effect. Study what I did here and take note of the widths/heights of the TV set portions, that is one of the problems in your current code (the top and bottom have to be narrow so not to cover your clickable area). While I understand the CSS here can be a bit of a learning curve for someone new to this, I assure you this is the direction you should be headed for creating quality Web work.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an in depth post. I am working on redesigning my drawing to be one big drawing that I will separate into smaller drawings and then use divs as you said. Right now I have finals and such so I will have to take a small break from any coding. I will let you know when I start back up. Thanks again.

Comment: If I want to implement a scrollable frame, would it be best to do so in the css by changing the scroll to hidden, or within the div itself?

and is there a way to make it so only the x-axis scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap everything inside the outer television in a `<div>`
2. Create seperate HTML pages that just has the HTML of the content that you want inside the television.
3. Use [jQuery's AJAX get method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to get the HTML for the page without refreshing it.

e.g. Your "single" image is in a `<td>` with ID "rightframe". So when rightframe is clicked, you might want to get the html of a page called single.html and put that inside the television (let's assume your `<div>` or `<table>` that has the code has ID `content`):

```
$('#rightframe').click(function() {
    $.get('single.html', function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    });
});
```

Edit: For the sliding part, you would have to create two separate tables/divs side by side, one for the current page, and one for the page that is being loaded. Then you could use a jQuery plugin like Slidy http://www.wbotelhos.com/slidy/ to transition between them.

Personally I think it would be much cooler if you could put an animated GIF of TV white noise on the television while the page is loading :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot that was really helpful, I hope to eventually have a gif in each tv that is whitenoise until you mouseover, then it will be a quick gif of the television show :)

Comment: can you elaborate on how to create two separate tables/divs side by side?

does that have to be within the same html file, or could I have it link to a separate html file?

Comment: could you tell me how to initialize the first content that will enable me to click on the link #'rightframe'?

Comment: Your last question: in your html `<head>` section, put `<script type="text/javascript"> $( function() { **YOUR CODE HERE ** }); </script>`, the `$(function(){});` is a special jQuery construct that says "do this when the window loads". First question: It's not straightforward. If you're going to go for the white noise thing just forget the sliding transitions, because it's just a load of work that you will have to undo later.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Vzdu7/